# XPath - how to get data from an element, not including a nested element

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

```html
<li>
<code>Python</code>  is an interpreted, object-oriented, high-level programming language with dynamic semantics.
</li>
```

Which XPath can extract  `is an interpreted, object-oriented, high-level programming language with dynamic semantics.` text?

Comment: This is really not a good question - you have the JSON API, so this is kind of a "how do I build a web page" question using a JSON API.  Too broad or too opinionated for a good set of answers.

Comment: What do you think what the best wording for my problem?

Comment: @Joe or better to delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of xpath and parser, try either

```
string-join(//li//text())
```

or

```
string-join(//li//text(),'')
```

to get your desired text.